# Can I convert to my type from a function pointer in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a struct that wraps around a type alias provided by another crate. The type alias looks something like this:

```rust
type Operation = fn(i32) -> String;
```

My wrapper struct looks something like this:

```rust
struct Wrapper {
    operation: Operation
}
```

Easy enough. However, for developer convenience, I'd like to be able to convert from an `Operation` to a `Wrapper` using the `From` trait. So I added this implementation:

```rust
impl From<Operation> for Wrapper {
    fn from(operation: Operation) -> Self {
        Self {
            operation
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I then try to use that implementation, I get a compiler error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let wrapped = Wrapper::from(double);
}

fn double(arg: i32) -> String {
    (arg * 2).to_string()
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Wrapper: From<fn(i32) -> String {double}>` is not satisfied                                                                                             
  --> src/main.rs:16:19
   |
16 |     let wrapped = Wrapper::from(double);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<fn(i32) -> String {double}>` is not implemented for `Wrapper`
   |
   = help: the trait `From<fn(i32) -> String>` is implemented for `Wrapper`
```

As you can see it says that `From` is not implemented for `fn(i32) -> String {double}`, but is implemented for `fn(i32) -> String`. Is it possible to get the compiler to ignore this `{double}`, or can this only be done by using `double as Operation` whenever I call `Wrapper::from`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the expression `double` (as in `Wrapper::from(double)`) is *not* a function pointer of type `Operation`. It is actually a zero-sized value of an unnamed type that specifically refers to the function `double`. However, this value can be coerced into a function pointer. See [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.fn.html#creating-function-pointers) on the `fn` primitive type.

No matter how you slice and dice it, the user of your library always has to explicitly convert whatever concrete function they have from the anonymous value they can write down to the `fn` they need; there is simply no way to write down `double` (or whatever it is) without a type-coercion, and have the compiler "see" a naked function pointer.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

If you ditch the `From` trait and instead provide your own function (which behaves similar to `From`), you can achieve what you need:

```rust
type Operation = fn(i32) -> String;

struct Wrapper {
    operation: Operation,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn wrap(operation: Operation) -> Self {
        Self { operation }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let wrapper = Wrapper::wrap(double);
    println!("{}", (wrapper.operation)(10));
}

fn double(arg: i32) -> String {
    (arg * 2).to_string()
}
```

```
20
```

My understanding is that it just doesn't work with the `From` trait because the type resolution of the generic happens *before* the coercion, and therefore `double` is not yet a the function pointer it needs to be.

But if you have your own method, the coercion target is clear from the beginning on and the function can be converted to a function pointer successfully.

If you *want* to use the `From` trait, you need to trigger the coercion *before* running the `.from()`, as you already realized:

```rust
let wrapper = Wrapper::from(double as Operation);
let wrapper: Wrapper = (double as Operation).into();
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Sadly, that won't work for me, as the actual wrapper type implements `From` for multiple source types.